# Dynamically append html table cell

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am creating a responsive table:

```
<h2>Workflows</h2>

    <table class="tablesaw" data-tablesaw-mode="columntoggle" data-tablesaw-minimap>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="persist">Workflow Name</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="1">Title</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-sortable-default-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Assigned To</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">Status</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">Due Date</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Button Status</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="1">Created</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Description</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Modified</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Pedecessors</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Priority</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Related Items</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Start Date</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Task Group</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Created By</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Modified By</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">% Complete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="title"><a href="#"></a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

While appending specific inputs, I am cycling through the table cells with this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table.tablesaw tbody tr').each(function(){
    $('tr td').each(function(){
        $('.title').append().html('<input type="text" />')
          .next().append().html('<input type="text" />')
          .next().append().html('<select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select>')
          .next().append().html('<select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select>')
          .next().append().html('<input type="datetime" value="Select Date" />')
          .next().append().html('<select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select>')
          .next().append().html('<input type="datetime" value="Select Date" />')
          .next().append().html('<input type="text" />')
          .next().append().html('<input type="datetime" value="Date" />')
          .next().append().html('<input type="text" />')
          .next().append().html('<select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select>')
          .next().append().html('<input type="text" />')
          .next().append().html('<input type="datetime" value="Date" />')
          .next().append().html('<input type="text" />')
          .next().append().html('<input type="text" />')
          .next().append().html('<input type="text" />')
          .next().append().html('<input type="range" />');
    });
});
```

});

My question:
Is this essentially the most effective and efficient method to accomplish dynamically modifying the cells whenever table rows are added?

Comment: I am trying to avoid specifying the table cell content with the html code, I'd rather leave the cell blank and append via jQuery, unless another method accomplishes the task more effectively. Also, I can include any additional code, if required, but based on this simple function, it seemed irrelevant.

Comment: not really. it's a lot of dom fiddling. you'd probably be better off keepign a copy of those row in a hidden/detached node somewhere, and simply cloning it into the necessary spot. that'd be one single mod of the dom.

Comment: I agree. Create one row with the expected inputs and clone it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is:

```js
$(function () {
  var rowTamplate = $('table.tablesaw tbody tr').eq(0);
  var rowContent = ['<input type="text" />','<input type="text" />','<select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select>',
                    '<select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select>', '<input type="datetime" value="Select Date" />',
                    '<select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select>', '<input type="datetime" value="Select Date" />',
                    '<input type="text" />', '<input type="datetime" value="Date" />', '<input type="text" />', '<select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select>',
                    '<input type="text" />', '<input type="datetime" value="Date" />', '<input type="text" />', '<input type="text" />', '<input type="text" />', '<input type="range" />'];
  var rowToadd = rowTamplate.clone();
  rowToadd.find('td').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).append(rowContent[index]);
  });
  rowToadd.insertAfter('table.tablesaw tr:eq(2)');
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    rowToadd.clone().insertAfter('table.tablesaw tr:eq(2)');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Workflows</h2>

<table class="tablesaw" data-tablesaw-mode="columntoggle" data-tablesaw-minimap>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="persist">Workflow Name</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="1">Title</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-sortable-default-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Assigned To</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">Status</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">Due Date</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Button Status</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="1">Created</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Description</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Modified</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Pedecessors</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Priority</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Related Items</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Start Date</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Task Group</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Created By</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Modified By</th>
        <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">% Complete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="title"><a href="#"></a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title"><a href="#"></a><input type="text" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Select Date"></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Select Date"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Date"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Date"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="range"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title"><a href="#"></a><input type="text" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2"></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Select Date"></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Select Date"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Date"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Date"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="range"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title"><a href="#"></a><input type="text" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="3"></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Select Date"></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Select Date"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Date"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="Date"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="range"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have 3 questions about your proposal, 1st, is the variable supposed to be rwoContent or rowContent? Just for the sake of naming conventions I was thinking it's a minor typo. 2nd, is, while running the code snippet, the table cells are not coinciding with the proper cell headers, is there a break in the function? how can it be fixed and display properly? and 3rd, is, this looks much cleaner, but is it more efficient when modifying the elements in the DOM? This table will be residing on a sharepoint server for  personnel workflows, so realistically, there could be over 1k rows per table.

Comment: I tossed your code into codepen and it was just missing a few entries for the cells, it does run a lot better than mine. Thanks for the help! Now I just get to format all of the inputs and automatically populate some of the values based on the database, woo :/

Comment: I would if I could, but I unfortunately can't vote. I don't have rep to do so.

Comment: after applying this to the site, it unfortunately doesn't quite play properly, it's actually appending 100 blank table rows with the cell layouts in them, but only after the content that exists.