# Add Table Row With Appended Data On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is an expansion of a previous question [Dynamically append html table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814497/dynamically-append-html-table-cell) and the html has been slightly changed.

```
<div class="docs-main">
<h2>Workflows</h2>
<table class="tablesaw" data-tablesaw-mode="stack" data-tablesaw-sortable data-tablesaw-sortable-switch data-tablesaw-minimap data-tablesaw-mode-switch>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="persist">Workflow Name</th>
            <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-sortable-default-col data-tablesaw-priority="1">Title</th>
            <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Assigned To</th>
            <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">Status</th>
            <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Due Date</th>
            <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="5">Outcome</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="e1">
                    <option value="1">Name 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Name 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Name 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="e2">
                    <option value="#00ff00">Complete</option>
                    <option value="#ffff00">In Progress</option>
                    <option value="#ff0000">Incomplete</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="datetime" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Add Row" />
```

The updated jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/marcwebdude/48ng08tq/13/ . The problem is the append function at lines 47-64 where it is automatically appending a row.

```
$(function () {
    var rowTamplate = $('table.tablesaw tbody tr').eq(0);
    var rowContent = [
        '<input type="text" value="Name" />',
        '<input type="text" value="Title" />',
        '<select><option>Name 1</option><option>Name 2</option><option>Name 3</option></select>',
        '<select><option value="#00ff00">Complete</option><option value="#ffff00">In Progress</option><option value="#ff0000">Incomplete</option></select>',
        '<input type="datetime" value="Select Date" />',
        '<input type="text" />'
    ];
    var rowToadd = rowTamplate.clone();
    rowToadd.find('td').each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).append(rowContent[index]);
    });
    rowToadd.insertAfter('table.tablesaw tr:eq(2)');
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        rowToadd.clone().insertAfter('table.tablesaw tr:eq(2)');
}
```

I am looking for a solution that when the button is clicked it adds a row with the appended html. Not to automatically add it after a currently existing row. For instance if this table was blank, a button click would add a row with these 6 specified columns and the inputs that coincide with each cell.

The second issue with my existing script is that it's not formatting the appended html, when a row is added manually into the html file, it's formatting correctly, but not if it's appended via jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated jsfiddle with revised jquery is https://jsfiddle.net/marcwebdude/48ng08tq/73/ , and so far it's appending contents into the table correctly. Here's the html

```
<div class="docs-main">
    <h2>Workflows</h2>
    <table class="tablesaw" data-tablesaw-mode="stack" data-tablesaw-sortable data-tablesaw-sortable-switch data-tablesaw-minimap data-tablesaw-mode-switch>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="persist">Workflow Name</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-sortable-default-col data-tablesaw-priority="1">Title</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Assigned To</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">Status</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Due Date</th>
                <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="5">Outcome</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Row" id="button" />
</div>
```

and here's the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        $('.tablesaw').find('tbody').append($('<tr><td><input type="text" value="Name" /></td><td class="title"><input type="text" value="Title" /></td><td><select class="e1"><option value="0">-- User --</option><option>Name 1</option><option>Name 2</option><option>Name 3</option></select></td><td><select class="e2"><option value="#fff">-- Status --</option><option value="#00ff00">Complete</option><option value="#ffff00">In Progress</option><option value="#ff0000">Incomplete</option></select></td><td><input type="datetime" value="Select Date" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>'));
        $('.e1').select2();
        $('.e2').select2().on('change', function () {
            $(this).next()
                .find('.select2-selection')
                .css({ backgroundColor: this.value });
        }).trigger('change');
        });
    });
```

This appends the correct data into each cell as well as inherits styles once the row is created.

Comment: is this the answer of your question?